# Magento: How to fill form data after its saved?

Tags: php, forms, magento

I am creating a custom form for my extension. In the form I have few fields that I save in database. My problem is that once I save the fields they get saved in DB but after the page refresh the data in the fields gets empty.

I want these fields data to remain in the fields. How do I do that? Is there a way to do that.

Form code is in this file    `app\code\community\CompanyNmae\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Suretaxconfig\Edit\Form.php`

and save config method is in this file

```
app\code\community\CompanyNmae\ModuleName\controllers\Adminhtml\ModuleController.php
```

Code for `Form.php` is here. There no HTML or PHTML used in the project for my extension.

```
<?php

class CompanyName_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_ModuleConfig_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form (
                array('id'=>'edit_form', 'action'=>$this->getData('action'), 'method'=>'post')
                );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('modulename')->__('ModuleName Settings'),
            'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));

        $fieldset->addField('companycode', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'companycode',
            'label' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Client Number'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Client Number'),
            'required' => true,
            'after_element_html' => '<small>Enter Client Number</small>'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('validationkey', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'validationkey',
            'label' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Validation Key'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Validation Key'),
            'required' => true,
            'after_element_html' => '<small>Enter Company Validation Key </small>'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('select_provider_type', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Default Provider Type'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'providertype',
          'onclick' => "",
          'onchange' => "",
          'value'  => '1',
          'values' => array('70' => '70', '99' => '99'),
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => false,
          'after_element_html' => '<small>Default Provider Type</small>',
          'tabindex' => 1
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch data from database and fill that data into fields or you can use session and store form post values into it before saving the data into database and when it redirects on your form page you can check if values are exists then you fill them in form

Comment: How and which page do I do that.

Comment: please show your code of form page then i can explain much better

Comment: may be this one will help you. http://rtdivision.com/keep-form-fields-error-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little confusable, I'm assuming that you want to keep fields data field after the form submit....

Is this is the scenario then you can use PHP Sessions to store data in sessions and check on page load if session is set then display it.

Like:

**PHP**

```
session_start();
// you can set session on form submit using if(isset($_POST)){//set session here}
$_SESSION['example'] = "Example Value";
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="example" value="<?=(isset($_SESSION['example']) ? $_SESSION['example'] : ''); ?>"/>
```

Comment: I have now added the code. Please explain me where in above file I add the extra code. I am very new to Magento and my online course is not done yet so not very familiar yet.